# How can you use a layout with a JS response?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to wrap all of my javascript responses to the client in a layout which deals with additional things such as errors.

I can't seem to figure out how to get a JS response (i.e. `users/create.js.html`) to cascade up into a javascript specific layout (e.g. `layouts/applicaton.js.erb`).

Is this possible?

Comment: what's a "layout", in this context?  Do you mean a message structure?  Why not simply use a JS object, serialized to JSON.  If I am understanding the scenario, this would fit well.

Comment: TY but I do actually mean a full wrapping, not just the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the layout in the controller action. As I'm not sure about js layouts you might need to rename it to something other than application. Also I don't know if you can include the extension but play about with it and report back :) :

```
def action
  render :layout => 'js_layout'
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed thank you. I'm not sure why I didn't register this before. Do you know whether one could enforce a particular format-layout application-wide rather than on a per-controller basis. e.g. all JS requests have to have a layout of `application.js.erb` ? I'd much prefer to make the layout use implicit rather than explicit

Comment: You could include it in application_controller.rb and override it in your actions or controllers as required. How did it go with the file extension and naming convention?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant by that - can you elaborate?